# WPF MVVM Validation using data annotation

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm, data-annotations

I am New in wpf mvvm architecture.Insert updates are working with linq to sql.I need to give the validation using data annotation.How can we provide validation using data annotation.Can any one give some good example?

My Model is

```
namespace EmployeeApp.Model
{
    public class Employee : ObservableObject
    {
        #region Constructor
        public Employee(int empId = 0, string empName = "", int age = 0)
        {
            _empId = empId;
            _empName = empName;
            _age = age;

        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        private int _empId = 0;

        public int EmpId
        {
            get { return _empId; }
            set
            {
                _empId = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ID");
            }
        }

        private string _empName = string.Empty;

        public string EmpName
        {
            get { return _empName; }
            set
            {
                _empName = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Name");
            }
        }

        private int _age = 0;

        public int Age
        {
            get { retuenter code heren _age; }
            set
            {
                _age = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Age");
            }
        }


        #endregion
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the updated solution?

Answer (score 13):

For example: [Code MSDN Reference Data Annotations](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Validation-in-MVVM-using-12dafef3)

Add the reference in your model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Then just the following for your properties.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is required")] 
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is Invalid")] 
public string Email 
{ 
    get { return GetValue(() => Email); } 
    set { SetValue(() => Email, value); } 
}
```

**Updated with complete example:**
Your class should use a base class `PropertyChangedNotification`
Create the clas `PropertyChangedNotification` like the following(in the page on the link you can find it)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace EmployeeApp.Notification
{
   public abstract class PropertyChangedNotification : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
   {
      #region Fields

      private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

      #endregion

      #region Protected

      /// <summary>
      /// Sets the value of a property.
      /// </summary>
      /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
      /// <param name="propertySelector">Expression tree contains the property definition.</param>
      /// <param name="value">The property value.</param>
      protected void SetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector, T value)
      {
         string propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);

         SetValue<T>(propertyName, value);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Sets the value of a property.
      /// </summary>
      /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
      /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property.</param>
      /// <param name="value">The property value.</param>
      protected void SetValue<T>(string propertyName, T value)
      {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
         {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
         }

         _values[propertyName] = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets the value of a property.
      /// </summary>
      /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
      /// <param name="propertySelector">Expression tree contains the property definition.</param>
      /// <returns>The value of the property or default value if not exist.</returns>
      protected T GetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector)
      {
         string propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);

         return GetValue<T>(propertyName);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets the value of a property.
      /// </summary>
      /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
      /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property.</param>
      /// <returns>The value of the property or default value if not exist.</returns>
      protected T GetValue<T>(string propertyName)
      {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
         {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
         }

         object value;
         if (!_values.TryGetValue(propertyName, out value))
         {
            value = default(T);
            _values.Add(propertyName, value);
         }

         return (T)value;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Validates current instance properties using Data Annotations.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="propertyName">This instance property to validate.</param>
      /// <returns>Relevant error string on validation failure or <see cref="System.String.Empty"/> on validation success.</returns>
      protected virtual string OnValidate(string propertyName)
      {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
         {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
         }

         string error = string.Empty;
         var value = GetValue(propertyName);
         var results = new List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>(1);
         var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(
             value,
             new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
             {
                MemberName = propertyName
             },
             results);

         if (!result)
         {
            var validationResult = results.First();
            error = validationResult.ErrorMessage;
         }

         return error;
      }

      #endregion

      #region Change Notification

      /// <summary>
      /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
      /// </summary>
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      /// <summary>
      /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
      protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
         this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

         PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
         if (handler != null)
         {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
         }
      }

      protected void NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector)
      {
         var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
         if (propertyChanged != null)
         {
            string propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
         }
      }

      #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members

      #region Data Validation

      string IDataErrorInfo.Error
      {
         get
         {
            throw new NotSupportedException("IDataErrorInfo.Error is not supported, use IDataErrorInfo.this[propertyName] instead.");
         }
      }

      string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
      {
         get
         {
            return OnValidate(propertyName);
         }
      }

      #endregion

      #region Privates

      private string GetPropertyName(LambdaExpression expression)
      {
         var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
         if (memberExpression == null)
         {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
         }

         return memberExpression.Member.Name;
      }

      private object GetValue(string propertyName)
      {
         object value;
         if (!_values.TryGetValue(propertyName, out value))
         {
            var propertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType()).Find(propertyName, false);
            if (propertyDescriptor == null)
            {
               throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
            }

            value = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(this);
            _values.Add(propertyName, value);
         }

         return value;
      }

      #endregion

      #region Debugging

      /// <summary>
      /// Warns the developer if this object does not have
      /// a public property with the specified name. This 
      /// method does not exist in a Release build.
      /// </summary>
      [Conditional("DEBUG")]
      [DebuggerStepThrough]
      public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
      {
         // Verify that the property name matches a real,  
         // public, instance property on this object.
         if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
         {
            string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

            if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
               throw new Exception(msg);
            else
               Debug.Fail(msg);
         }
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Returns whether an exception is thrown, or if a Debug.Fail() is used
      /// when an invalid property name is passed to the VerifyPropertyName method.
      /// The default value is false, but subclasses used by unit tests might 
      /// override this property's getter to return true.
      /// </summary>
      protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }

      #endregion // Debugging Aides
   }
}
```

In your *view* you could add this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
           Name="txtEmail" 
           Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay, 
           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
           ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Width="100">
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
               Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, ElementName=txtEmail}" 
               Foreground="Red" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

About validation on button click, just implement the command and raise the notification there.

*Changes for validation on click*

View

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0"
           Name="txtTestValue" Text="{Binding MyTextValue, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Width="100">
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, ElementName=txtTestValue}" Foreground="Red" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
<Button Content="Validate" Command="{Binding ValidationCommand}">

</Button>
```

Model

```
ValidationCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteMyCommand,() => true);
```

....

```
public RelayCommand ValidationCommand
{
    get;
    private set;
}

private void ExecuteMyCommand()
{
    OnValidate("MyTextValue");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Then How can we implement this in the button click in the view

Comment: @blacai: there is just a very small bug in your code: ArgumentException constructor parameter called 'parameterName' should be name of the incorrect parameter, not value of the parameter. Use new ArgumentException("Invalid property name: " + propertyName, "propertyName"); istead of new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);

Comment: I really liked the "backing field" stored in a dictionary.